# ¿Cómo obtener una lista sin repeticiones ni duplicados en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sql

Tengo una base de datos en MongoDB de varias películas con información sobre ellas (actores que participaron, género, año, etc). Necesito una lista **sin repetidos** de los actores que hicieron películas de humor en 1993. Creo que tengo el código para obtener todos los actores que cumplen esta condición, pero si un actor participó en dos películas de humor de 1993, entonces este aparecerá dos veces en mi lista.

Consulta:

```
db.movies.find({genre: "Comedy", year:1993},{actors:1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con [db.collection.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) se obtienen los valores sin duplicados de un campo. Permite pasar una consulta como la que usabas como 2do parámetro.

```
db.movies.distinct("actors", {genre: "Comedy", year:1993})
```